# I am getting repeated values for group_concat

Tags: mysql

I have 10 tables while i am using group_concat i am getting multiple values.
The query is

```
SELECT 
  e.*,p.*,m.*,r.*,GROUP_CONCAT(q.QUALIFICATION,'#',q.SPECIALIZATION,'#',q.NAME_OF_INSTITUTION,'#',q.UNIVERSITY,'#',q.PLACE,'#',q.YEARS_OF_PASSING,'#',q.PERCENTAGE) AS qualifications,

  GROUP_CONCAT(ep.NAME_OF_ORGANIZATION,'#',ep.DESIGNATION,'#',ep.REPORTING_TO,'#',ep.PERIOD_FROM,'#',ep.PERIOD_TO,'#',ep.ANNUAL_CTC,'#',ep.RESONS_FOR_CHANGE,'#',ep.TOTAL_WORK_EXPERIENCE,'#',TOTAL_RELEVANT_EXPERIENCE) AS experience,
  GROUP_CONCAT(f.PARTICULARS,'#',f.NAME,'#',f.DATE_OF_BIRTH,'#',f.AGE,'#',f.GENDER,'#',f.OCCUPATION) AS familydetails,
  GROUP_CONCAT(l.sLANGUAGE_NAME,'#',l.sSPEAK,'#',l.sREAD,'#',l.sWRITE) AS languages,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ss.COMPUTER_SKILLS,'#',ss.TRAININGS_ATTENDED) AS skillset,
  GROUP_CONCAT(tc.NAME_OF_TRAININGS_CERTIFICATION,'#',tc.TRAININGS_CERTIFICATION_FROM,'#',tc.ISSUED_DATE,'#',tc.ISSUED_DATE) AS TRAININGS_AND_CERTIFICATION



 FROM
ACHIVEMENTS_REF e
    LEFT JOIN
BANK_DETAILS p ON e.USER_ID=p.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN EDUCATIONAL_QUALIFICATIONS q ON e.USER_ID=q.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE_MASTER m ON e.USER_ID=m.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN EXPERIENCE_PROFILE ep ON e.USER_ID=ep.USER_ID 
LEFT JOIN FAMILY_DETAILS f ON e.USER_ID=f.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN LANGUAGES l ON e.USER_ID=l.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_DETAILS r ON e.USER_ID=r.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN SKILL_SET ss ON e.USER_ID=ss.USER_ID
LEFT JOIN TRAININGS_AND_CERTIFICATION tc ON e.USER_ID=tc.USER_ID where e.USER_ID=1;
```

and i am getting the result as
 qualifications: B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,B tech#computers#cbit#jntu#hyderabad#2013#80,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computers#mathru sri#ou#secundrabae#2013#90,M tech #computer
                 experience: infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,oracle#software developer##2011#2013#100000#better#1#2,oracle#software developer##2011#2013#100000#better#1#2,oracle#software developer##2011#2013#100000#better#1#2,oracle#software developer##2011#2013#100000#better#1#2,oracle#software developer##2011#2013#100000#better#1#2,oracle#software developer##2011#2013#100000#better#1#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#software developer##2013#2015#200000#opportunity#2#2,infosyis#sof

I am getting repeated values how can i modify the query..?

Comment: you've got group_concat without any `group by` clauses? you should add one.

Comment: Are you sure you want `GROUP_CONCAT` and not good ole `CONCAT`